# To execute shell script from Sql prompt

Tags: unix, sqlplus

I have one shell script test.sh that displays 'WELCOME' and kept in unix server /home/xxx/

Now, I want to execute this from Sql prompt.

I tried with some code with sys priviledge.but could work and getting error like ORA-29540: class does not exist
and I think there is error while executing shell command.

Here, I have created all objects in the database.

can any one help me on this please ?.

Comment: Which sql do you use?

Comment: the error ORA is produced by oracle db I think

Comment: show how you are calling the shell script from the sql prompt. This tutorial might help http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_script_linux_shell_commands.htm

Comment: I added the `sqlplus` tag because of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I understand is you need to execute a shell script from sql prompt.

From the SQL*Plus prompt, do `!sh script_name`. (! is used to temporarily exit out of SQL*Plus and execute a shell command)

I created a sample.sh file on the home directory and it contains echo "welcome";

I started SQL*Plus and did

```
SQL> !sh sample.sh
```

The output is `welcome`

Also, when you get an ORA error, it is generally an Oracle error.